# How to rename value in column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, rename

I have a dataframe:

```
  id                 value
4_french:k_15          10
87_nov:k_82            82
11_nov:k_10            10
1_italian:k_11         9
```

I want to rename values in column id which have `nov:k_` giving them new id `k` so desired result must be:

```
  id                 value
4_french:k_15          10
k                      82
k                      10
1_italian:k_11         9
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace) and `regex` like below:

```
>>> df['id'] = df['id'].str.replace(r'.*nov:k_.*', 'k', regex= True)

>>> df
  id                 value
4_french:k_15          10
k                      82
k                      10
1_italian:k_11         9
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `contains` with `loc`

```
df.loc[df['id'].str.contains("nov:k_"), 'id'] = "k"
```

---

```
               id  value
0   4_french:k_15     10
1               k     82
2               k     10
3  1_italian:k_11      9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple for loop.

```
for i in df['id']:
    if "nov:k" in i:
        df = df.replace(i, 'k')
```